function is declared but never read: Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
I'm trying to make a vending machine page.
I'm using 2 js files and 2 html files
index.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="scroll-smooth">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.7.1/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-5Hs3dF2AEPkpNAR7UiOHba+lRSJNeM2ECkwxUIxC1Q/FLycGTbNapWXB4tP889k5T5Ju8fs4b1P5z/iB4nMfSQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Vending-Machine</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-[#121212]">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="topclass z-10 shadow-emerald-400 shadow-md">
            <nav class="mt-4 p-2 flex justify-between items-center border-b-violet-500 border-b-2">
                <img src="res/logo.png" alt="logo maybe...." class="w-[80px] rounded-full">
                <a class="hover:text-purple-500 text-white ml-12">Snacks</a>
                <a href="#quick-food" class="hover:text-purple-500 text-white">Quick-Food</a>
                <a href="#drinks" class="hover:text-orange-500 text-white">Drinks</a>
                <a href="./cart.html"><button><i class="fa fa-cart-plus text-[3ch] bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-500 to-orange-600 text-transparent duration-200 bg-clip-text hover:text-white transition ease-in-out"></i></button></a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="content ml-5">
            <div class="mt-4">
                <p class="text-3xl ml-3 bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-500 via-pink-500 to-orange-600 text-transparent bg-clip-text hover:translate-x-2 transition ease-in-out">Find Snacks Here <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></p> 
            </div>
            <div class="flex gap-x-4 w-[90vw] overflow-x-auto" id="snacks">
            <div  class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0">  
            <div>
                    <img src="res/snacks/skittels.jpg" alt="skittles img" class="w-[40vw]">
                    <p class="text-purple-400 text-center"><b>SKITTLES</b><br>Price: 100 ₹ <br>IN STOCK :<span id="skittelstock"> </span><br><button onclick="stockminus('skittelstock','sktnum','Skittles',100,'res/snacks/skittels.jpg')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button><span class="text-emerald-400" id="sktnum"></span><button onclick="stockplus('skittelstock','sktnum','Skittels',100,'res/snacks/skittels.jpg')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0">   
                <div >
                    <img src="res/snacks/mnms.jpg" alt="mnm's img" class="w-[40vw]">
                    <p class="text-purple-400 text-center"><b>M&M's</b><br>Price: 100 ₹ <br>IN STOCK : <span id="mnmstock"></span><br><button  onclick="stockminus('mnmstock','mnmnum','M&M\'s')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button><span class="text-emerald-400" id="mnmnum"></span><button onclick="stockplus('mnmstock','mnmnum','M&M\'s')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0">
                <div >
                    <img src="res/snacks/pepitos.webp" alt="pepitos img" class="w-[40vw]">
                    <p class="text-purple-400 text-center"><b>Pepitos</b><br>Price: 25 ₹ <br>IN STOCK: <span id="pepitostock"></span><br><button  onclick="stockminus('pepitostock','pepinum','Pepitos')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button><span class="text-emerald-400" id="pepinum"></span><button onclick="stockplus('pepitostock','pepinum','Pepitos')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0">
            <div >
                    <img src="res/snacks/pringles.jpg" alt="pringles img" class="w-[40vw]">
                    <p class="text-purple-400 text-center"><b>Pringles</b><br>Price: 80 ₹ <br>IN STOCK: <span id="pringlestock"></span> <br><button  onclick="stockminus('pringlestock','pringnum','Pringles')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button><span class="text-emerald-400" id="pringnum"></span><button onclick="stockplus('pringlestock','pringnum','Pringles')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-10">
                <p class="text-3xl ml-3 bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-500 via-pink-500 to-orange-600 text-transparent bg-clip-text hover:translate-x-2 transition ease-in-out">Find Quick-Food Here <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></p> 
            </div>
            <div class="flex gap-x-4 w-[90vw] overflow-x-auto" id="quick-food">
            <div  class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0">
            <div>
                    <img src="res/quickfood/chowmein.webp" alt="chowmein img" class="w-[40vw]">
                    <p class="text-purple-400 text-center"><b>Chowmein</b><br>Price: 89 ₹ <br>IN STOCK: <span id="chowmeinstock"></span><br><button  onclick="stockminus('chowmeinstock','chownum','Chowmein')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button><span class="text-emerald-400" id="chownum"></span><button onclick="stockplus('chowmeinstock','chownum','Chowmein')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0">
                <div >
                    <img src="res/quickfood/maggi.webp" alt="Maggi img" class="w-[40vw]">
                    <p class="text-purple-400 text-center"><b>Maggie</b><br>Price: 10 ₹ <br>IN STOCK: <span id="maggistock"></span><br><button  onclick="stockminus('maggistock','magnum','Maggie')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button><span class="text-emerald-400" id="magnum"></span><button onclick="stockplus('maggistock','magnum','Maggie')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0">
                <div >
                    <img src="res/quickfood/pizzaoats.png" alt="pizzaoats img" class="w-[40vw]">
                    <p class="text-purple-400 text-center"><b>Pizzaoats</b><br>Price: 50 ₹ <br>IN STOCK: <span id="pizzaoatstock"></span><br><button onclick="stockminus('pizzaoatstock','ponum','Pizzaoats')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button><span class="text-emerald-400" id="ponum"></span><button onclick="stockplus('pizzaoatstock','ponum','Pizzaoats')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0">
            <div >
                    <img src="res/quickfood/topramen.jpeg" alt="Top Ramen img" class="w-[40vw]">
                    <p class="text-purple-400 text-center"><b>Top Ramen</b><br>Price: 20 ₹ <br>IN STOCK: <span id="topramenstock"></span><br><button onclick="stockminus('topramenstock','topnum','Top Ramen')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button><span class="text-emerald-400" id="topnum"></span><button onclick="stockplus('topramenstock','topnum','Top Ramen')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-10">
                <p class="text-3xl ml-3 bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-500 via-pink-500 to-orange-600 text-transparent bg-clip-text hover:translate-x-2 transition ease-in-out">Find Drinks Here <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></p> 
            </div>
            <div class="flex gap-x-4 w-[90vw] overflow-x-auto" id="drinks">
            <div  class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0">
            <div>
                    <img src="res/Drinks/coke.jpg" alt="coke img" class="w-[40vw]">
                    <p class="text-purple-400 text-center"><b>Coca-Cola</b><br>Price: 40 ₹ <br>IN STOCK: <span id="cokestock"></span><br><button onclick="stockminus('cokestock','cokenum','Coca-Cola')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button><span class="text-emerald-400" id="cokenum"></span><button onclick="stockplus('cokestock','cokenum','Coca-Cola')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0">
                <div >
                    <img src="res/Drinks/monster.jpg" alt="Monster img" class="w-[40vw]">
                    <p class="text-purple-400 text-center"><b>Monster</b><br>Price: 40 ₹ <br>IN STOCK: <span id="monsterstock"></span><br><button onclick="stockminus('monsterstock','monnum','Monster')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button><span class="text-emerald-400" id="monnum"></span><button onclick="stockplus('monsterstock','monnum','Monster')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0">
                <div >
                    <img src="res/Drinks/outofstock.jpg" alt="Prime img" class="w-[40vw]">
                    <p class="text-purple-400 text-center"><b>Prime</b><br>Price: 300 ₹ <br>IN STOCK: <span id="primestock"></span><br><button onclick="stockminus('primestock','prmnum','Prime')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button><span class="text-emerald-400" id="prmnum"></span><button onclick="stockplus('primestock','prmnum','Prime')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0">
            <div >
                    <img src="res/Drinks/pepsi.jpg" alt="Pepsi img" class="w-[40vw]">
                    <p class="text-purple-400 text-center"><b>Pepsi</b><br>Price: 40 ₹ <br>IN STOCK: <span id="pepsistock"></span><br><button onclick="stockminus('pepsistock','pepnum','Pepsi')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button><span class="text-emerald-400" id="pepnum"></span><button onclick="stockplus('pepsistock','pepnum','Pepsi')" ><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



this is script.js


import { addtocart } from "./cart";
addtocart(quantity, name, price, imgurl);

//for fun
var fun =0
//loading the html file first cus to get empty spans
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    //getting all span files as ids
    skits =  document.getElementById('skittelstock');
    mnms =       document.getElementById('mnmstock');
    pepis =   document.getElementById('pepitostock');
    prings = document.getElementById('pringlestock');
    chowms= document.getElementById('chowmeinstock');
    mags =     document.getElementById('maggistock');
    pizots= document.getElementById('pizzaoatstock');
    toprs = document.getElementById('topramenstock');
    cokes =     document.getElementById('cokestock');
    mons =   document.getElementById('monsterstock');
    primes =   document.getElementById('primestock');
    peps =     document.getElementById('pepsistock');
    //setting the stocks
    skits.textContent =  '30';
    mnms.textContent =   '20';
    pepis.textContent =  '30';
    prings.textContent = '20';
    chowms.textContent = '15';
    mags.textContent =   '20';
    pizots.textContent = '30';
    toprs.textContent =  '15';
    cokes.textContent =  '10';
    mons.textContent =   '10';
    primes.textContent =  '0';
    peps.textContent =   '15';
    //I hate KSI yeah
    primes.style.color = 'red';
});

//functions for stock management
function stockplus(stockid,spanid,name,price,imgurl){
    if(document.getElementById(stockid).textContent == 0){
        fun += 1;
        document.getElementById(stockid).style.color = 'red';
        alert('NO ITEM LEFT');
        if(fun >= 3)
        alert("seriously bro!?");//hehehe
        return;
    }
    //managing the stocks and quantitiy in cart
    document.getElementById(stockid).textContent -= 1;
    document.getElementById(spanid).textContent = Number(document.getElementById(spanid).textContent)+1;
    cart.addtocart(quantity,name,price,imgurl)
}
function stockminus(stockid,spanid,name,price,imgurl){
    if(document.getElementById(stockid).textContent == 0){
        return;
    }
    //manually setting the stock limits :(
    if((stockid == 'skittelstock' ||stockid == 'pepitostock'||stockid == 'pizzaoatstock')&&document.getElementById(stockid).textContent >= 30 
    ||(stockid == 'mnmstock' ||stockid == 'pringlestock'||stockid == 'maggistock')&&document.getElementById(stockid).textContent >= 20
    ||(stockid == 'chowmeinstock' ||stockid == 'topramenstock'||stockid == 'pepsistock')&&document.getElementById(stockid).textContent >= 15
    ||(stockid == 'cokestock' ||stockid == 'monsterstock')&&document.getElementById(stockid).textContent >= 10
    ){
    return;
    } 
    //managing the stocks and quantity in cart
    document.getElementById(stockid).textContent = Number(document.getElementById(stockid).textContent) +1;
    quantity = document.getElementById(spanid).textContent = Number(document.getElementById(spanid).textContent)-1;
    cart.addtocart(quantity,name,price,imgurl)
}



this is cart.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.7.1/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-5Hs3dF2AEPkpNAR7UiOHba+lRSJNeM2ECkwxUIxC1Q/FLycGTbNapWXB4tP889k5T5Ju8fs4b1P5z/iB4nMfSQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="cart.js"></script>
    <title>Cart</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-[#121212]">
    <div class="container">
        <div>
        <a href="./index.html"><button class="float-right z-10 mt-4 text-[3ch] text-orange-500 mr-4"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-16">
            <li id="cart">
            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



this is cart.js


export function addtocart(quantity,name,price,imgurl){
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = `${name} - ${quantity} x ₹${price} - ${imgurl}`;
    cart.appendChild(li);
}



I called stockplus from an html file using onclick. I have imported cart.js and cart.js has a function addtocart(). I am also using tailwindcss as CDN;
I'm currently trying to make only Skittle Work
the error i get is :
index.html:34 Uncaught ReferenceError: stockplus is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:34:424)
No errors the function should be called and addtocart() should work

please [edit] your question to include a [mre]

There's no reference to using stockplus in your code. Like the previous comment said, please add a reproducible reference. It's probably due to script tags being added in the DOM in the wrong place, imported incorrectly etc.

<script type="module" - the processing of the script content is deferred when you embed it as a module, and that's likely the reason the function is not known, when the parser encounters the onclick attribute on the element.

Thanks but can you please tell me how to fix this.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

As @C3roe mentioned, the error you're getting is apparently because you're using <script type="module" ... for your script.js. You were doing this because on script.js, you imported addtoCart function from another script (cart.js).
script.js
import { addtocart } from "./cart";            // <-- THIS PART
addtocart(quantity, name, price, imgurl);

//for fun
var fun =0
//loading the html file first cus to get empty spans
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

// ...

One quick fix that can be done is to just redeclare that addtoCart function inside your script.js so you don't have to import it.
script.js
// import { addtocart } from "./cart";             // <-- NO LONGER NEEDED
function addtocart(quantity, name, price, imgurl) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = `${name} - ${quantity} x ₹${price} - ${imgurl}`;
  cart.appendChild(li);
}

addtocart(quantity, name, price, imgurl);

//for fun
var fun = 0
//loading the html file first cus to get empty spans
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  //getting all span files as ids
  // ....


Now on your index.html, you don't need to specify type='module' for your script.js.
index.html
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>  <!-- CHANGE THIS PART -->
<script src="script.js"></script>                <!-- TO BE LIKE THIS -->

I've tested this on my local machine and it doesn't throw the error you specified but instead pops up an alert:


But I need to add list elements to cart which is in cart.html

Yeah, you can keep your cart.js and cart.html. You just need to re-declare that addtoCart function inside script.js @BALAVINAYAKAMD
